# Action Script 3 - Multiple Movie Button Clips?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, action, flash-cs5

So I have a code, shown below:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

instance160.stop();

function playMovie(event:MouseEvent):void 

{ 
instance160.play();
} 
button160.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMovie);
```

and I want to add multiple buttons, not just this one. I figured out by trial and error that I couldn't just consecutively list the instances, I also found I couldn't just replicate the code and change the instance names. I just need to know how to go about having multiple buttons/clips. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Event" class (which MouseEvent extends) has a property called "currentTarget", which passes a reference to whatever object dispatched that event. So you can do something like this:

```
myClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMovie, false, 0, true);
myClip2.addEVentListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMovie, false, 0, true);
...
myClip9999.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMovie, false, 0, true);

function playMovie(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.currentTarget.play();
}
```

Is that more or less what you were looking for?

Comment: Myk, I will treasure your little bit of help forever if I figure this out and it works - either way I still really appreciate it. I'm trying right now to mesh your bit of code with my little piece, not having any luck just yet but your knowledge is very awesome of you to offer and helpful! (because at least I can try some more different things now)

Comment: Well, so what is "instance160"? Is that just a movie clip that you put on the stage in Flash and didn't assign a name to?

Comment: So pretty much i'm making a what I thought would be a simple campus map. I made a legend, and for each room on the legend "buttonXXX" corresponds to the named instance animation in which the room/pathway fades in, so I named all my little clips with the room fading in "instanceXXX" just so I wouldn't get confused.

Comment: I was putting the other instances and buttons under the original instance160 previously, but then when ever a button was clicked it would play all the clips instead of one at a time, hence me desperately seeking help. :-S

Answer (score 0):

I use this small class that I made a while back - it makes adding listeners to multiply buttons quicker, easier and cleaner:

```
package
{
    public class ButtonCollection extends Object
    {
        // current list
        private var _clist:Array = [];

        /**
         * Merge instances of SimpleButton with listeners
         * @param list A list of buttons and listeners to merge
         */
        public function merge(...list):void
        {
            var i:Object;
            for each(i in list)
            {
                i.button.addEventListener(i.event, i.callback);
                _clist[_clist.length] = i;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Removes all previously added listeners
         */
        public function clear():void
        {
            var i:Object;
            for each(i in _clist)
            {
                i.button.removeEventListener(i.event, i.callback);
            }

            _clist = [];
        }
    }
}
```

**Use:**

This is how I use this class to add some listeners to two buttons I have created with instance names **a** and **b**.

```
var bc:ButtonCollection = new ButtonCollection();

bc.merge(
    {button: a, event: MouseEvent.CLICK, callback: _click},
    {button: b, event: MouseEvent.CLICK, callback: _click},
    {button: b, event: MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, callback: _mouseOver}
);

function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(e.target.name + " was clicked");
}

function _mouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(e.target.name + " was rolled over");
}
```

The class also gives you an easy option to remove all the previously added listeners when you're done:

```
bc.clear();
```